# Get specific result without using loop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've a table in which data is like this for single user

**ID - Number - SubNumber - Name**

`1   101        201101     Jack`
`2   101        201102     Jack`
`3   101        201103     Jack`
`4   101        201107     Jack`
`5   101        201111     Jack`
`6   101        201112     Jack`
`7   101        201113     Jack`
`8   101        201161     Jack`
`9   101        201162     Jack`
`10  101        201163     Jack`
`11  101        201164     Jack`
`12  101        201165     Jack`

I want to get records like this `without using any kind of loop.`

**Number - Name -  SubNumber**

`101     Jack     (201101-201103, 201107, 201111-201113, 201161-201165)`

Currently I'm able to get records in form of this

**Number - Name -  SubNumber**

`101     Jack    (201101,201102,201103, 201107, 201111.201112,201113, 201161,201162,201163,201164,201165)`

**Query to get upper result is**

```
SELECT  Number, Name
,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(SubNumber AS VARCHAR(50)) [text()]
     FROM [Table] 
     WHERE Number= t.Number
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
    .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') SubNumber
FROM [Table] t
GROUP BY Number,Name
having Number= '101'
```

Am totally stuck over here. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: [regex](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)
,

[group concat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451605/how-to-use-group-concat-in-a-concat-in-mysql)

Comment: The first part of your issue is a "gaps-and-islands" problem. So, the solution could be to first use a gaps-and-islands query and the output with your XML concatenation query. Which version of SQL-Server are you working on? (it's easier in 2012+ versions than previous ones.)

Comment: @ninjabber There is no need for regex (there never is ;) and SQL-Server has no `GROUP_CONCAT()` function (that's why they use `FOR XML PATH`).

Comment: @ypercube oops am using 2005 -_-

Comment: @ypercube, thanks. Should pay more attention. 
I do not agree about the regex but lets leave this subject for another time :)

Answer (score 3):

First add a `row_number()` value to the mix, because I'm guessing you can't rely on `ID` to have no gaps.

```
WITH NumberedRows AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number, Name ORDER BY SubNumber) AS RowNum
  FROM [Table]
)
```

--now compare RowNum to SubNumber. When the difference changes, there's been a gap in the sequence of SubNumber values.

```
, Diffs AS (
  SELECT *, SubNumber - RowNum AS TheDiff
  FROM NumberedRows
)
, Ranges AS (
  SELECT Number, Name,
    MIN(SubNumber) AS StartRange, 
    MAX(SubNumber) AS EndRange
  FROM Diffs
  GROUP BY Number, Name, TheDiff
)
, RangeStrings AS (
  SELECT Number, Name, 
    CASE WHEN StartRange = EndRange 
         THEN CAST(StartRange AS VARCHAR(10))
         ELSE CAST(StartRange AS VARCHAR(10)) + '-' + CAST(EndRange AS VARCHAR(10))
    END AS RangeString
  FROM Ranges
)
```

--And then just do your concatenation as you have already solved. :)

```
SELECT ...
FROM RangeStrings;
```